# Timer.Tick is not firing in webpart mobile adapter

Tags: 2010, mobile

I'm trying to use a Timer in my mobile adapter page (SharePoint 2010). But seems that the event Timer.Tick is not firing. Anyone knows if System.Web.UI.Timer is compatible with WebPartMobileAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for several days trying to get a timer to work on a sharepoint 2010 webpart. I've just got it going.

I created the timer as a global variable.

```
Dim WithEvents _timer As New System.Timers.Timer
```

Then in the Page_Load event I added it's properties

```
AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
With _timer
    .Interval = 500
    .Enabled = True
End With
```

The method itself is like this:

```
Public Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles _timer.Elapsed
    SetImageUrl()
End Sub
```

I have the timer calling another method that sets an image to an image control on the page.